# Why do I receive 'file open error' message?

Tags: 16.04, error-handling, signature

I am trying to download swift 3.1.1 using ubuntu16.04 using the tutorial found at this link: 
https://swift.org/download/#using-downloads

However, when I try to verify the signature file (step 4), I get

```
gpg: can't open `swift-3.1.1-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04.tar.gz.sig'
gpg: verify signatures failed: file open error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing the file isn't where you think it is. To check, run `[[ -f swift-3.1.1-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04.tar.gz.sig ]] && echo yes || echo no`.

Comment: Someone trying to install Tor had the same problem: [link](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/6461)